# How to enable Gzip in NginX ubuntu server

Tags: nginx, gzip, digital-ocean

I followed this tutorial 
https://davidwalsh.name/enable-gzip

and did following changes on my server to enable Gzip

```
$ # nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf
```

Then added these line

```
gzip on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
```

Then save and executed this command

$ service nginx reload

but it fails all the time ,

I tried commenting the first line of the file , ie.gzip on but still NginX is failling to load

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
* Reloading nginx configuration nginx                                   [fail]
```

any help

Comment: `it fails all the time`: what does it mean? The `nginx` doesn't reload? What is the error message?

Comment: the error message is  'FAIL' in the console

Comment: @uzsolt i updated my question

Comment: Ah. Please post output of `nginx -t`.